# Some search results link to main page instead of post

Tags: search

Some search results link as follows:

> [domain]/?es_template=[post title]

Which takes you to the main site, instead of the post.

Working search result links look like this:

> [domain]/?p=[permalink number]

Other information:

- Twenty Twelve theme
- I have never messed around with customizing anything, other than installing plugins, etc. In case that matters, here is a list of active plugins: Akismet, Backup Guard Pro, Contact Form 7, Email subscribers, Insert Headers and Footers, Loginizer Security, Replyable.
- All of the search results that link to main page have Oct. 18, 2017 as date of post.
- I have never changed permalink format/structure.

How do I fix this?

Comment: "es" sounds like the initials of "Email Subscribers", what does this plugin ?

Comment: It sends out emails to a list of subscribers when I make a new post.

Comment: then I think that the template show nothing usefull and these links should not appears in the results of the search. Report this problem to the developper of this plugin, we cannot help you more here because this is not a opensource plugin.

Comment: Thanks! I deactivated the plugin, and the phantom links went away.